# Python subprocess.call() add prefix to each stdout and stderr line

Tags: python, datetime, logging, subprocess, stdout

I am using python to run some shell scripts, RScripts, python programs etc. These programs may run for a long time and may output a lot of (logging)info to stdout and stderr. I am using the following (Python 2.6) code which works fine:

```
stdoutFile=open('stdout.txt', 'a')
stderrFile=open('stderr.txt', 'a')
subprocess.call(SHELL_COMMAND, shell=True, stdout=stdoutFile, stderr=stderrFile)
stdoutFile.close()
stderrFile.close()
```

This is mainly logging info that goes to the files and this info can be generated over long periods of time. Therefore i was wondering if it is possible to prefix each line with date and time?

For example if i would currently log:

```
Started
Part A done
Part B done
Finished
```

Then i would like it to be:

```
[2012-12-18 10:44:23] Started
[2012-12-18 12:26:23] Part A done
[2012-12-18 14:01:56] Part B done
[2012-12-18 22:59:01] Finished
```

Note: *Modifying the programs that i run is not and option as this python code kinda like a wrapper to these programs.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of providing files to the `stdout` and `stderr` arguments of `subprocess.call()`, create a `Popen` object directly and create `PIPE`s, then read off those pipes in this manager script and prepend whatever tags you want before writing to whatever log file you want.

```
def flush_streams_to_logs(proc, stdout_log, stderr_log):
    pipe_data = proc.communicate()
    for data, log in zip(pipe_data, (stdout_log, stderr_log)):
        # Add whatever extra text you want on each logged message here
        log.write(str(data) + '\n')

with open('stdout.txt', 'a') as stdout_log, open('stderr.txt', 'a') as stderr_log:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(SHELL_COMMAND, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while proc.returncode is None:
        flush_streams_to_logs(proc, stdout_log, stderr_log)
    flush_streams_to_logs(proc, stdout_log, stderr_log)
```

Note that `communicate()` blocks until the subprocess exits.  You may want to use the subprocess' streams directly so you have more real-time logging, but then you have to handle concurrency and buffer fill states yourself.

Comment: I don't think the 2nd option works, as they are lacking the `.fileno()` method which is used to (directly) write to. Nevertheless +1 for the first one.

Comment: Ahh, interesting, looks like you're right.  I'll remove the second bit.